# What is the most complex plant form?

Tags: taxonomy

At school we were told on scale of 0 through 1000 the animal kingdom ranges from amoeba the simplest/primitive being at 0, and Humans the most complex animals at 1000; what are the equivalent complexity species (?) in the plant kingdom? What is the least complex plant, and the most complex?

Comment: "Complexity" is a notoriously subjective and difficult-to-define term. Complexity differences between amoebas and vertebrates are hard to dispute, but amongst plants is a different story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That whole thing of being more complex is non-sense, you can't say that for animals and you can't say that for plants either. It all depends on how you look at it. Average number of cells? Size of genome? Size of the proteome? Adaptability to different environments? Mental abilities? You can't place human on the top of any of them (maybe we could argue about if you define it as mental abilities but that doesn't sound right) and you can't place amoeba at the bottom either.

Also, if you look at a phylogenetic tree, an organism is also not more complex by the number of nodes it has behind them (I've seen people thinking this means more evolved and associate that with more complex).

Answer (score 0):

The venus fly trap would certainly appear one of the most complex plants.
The plant almost 'bridges' a lifeform gap.